# session_start returns true but does not work when session_name contains space

Tags: php, session

Can someone explain if this is a correct behaviour from PHP, I was expecting session_start() to return false and to get a warning saying that session_name contains illegal characters.

Code to reproduce:

```
<?php
session_name('m m');
var_dump(session_start());

if(!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
     $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
}
else {
     $_SESSION['count']++;
}

echo session_name();
echo $_SESSION['count'];
```

Run it once:

`bool(true) m m0`

reload page:

`bool(true) m m0`

Should have been (if session was working):

`bool(true) m m1`

`session_start()` returns true which indicates the session has started. The `$_SESSION['count']` indicates that is does not work. There is no warning on illegal characters in the session name.

I can not find any hints on the manual page, nor a definition on what is valid characters for a session.

Comment: put `var_dump(session_start());` on top

Comment: You have to call `session_name()` before `session_start()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP generates something like this:

```
Set-Cookie: m+m=unttot9siteipcsrc0r064hn37; path=/
```

... and the browser (Firefox/23) sends this back:

```
Cookie: m+m=unttot9siteipcsrc0r064hn37
```

So far so good. But then PHP generates a new session ID:

```
Set-Cookie: m+m=7tmi7kd8n27ef3qdk5q706gk85; path=/
```

Is it a bug? I'd say it isn't since [your session name is clearly invalid](https://www.php.net/session_name):

> The session name references the name of the session, which is used in cookies and URLs (e.g. PHPSESSID). **It should contain only
> alphanumeric characters**; it should be short and descriptive (i.e.
> for users with enabled cookie warnings). If name is specified, the
> name of the current session is changed to its value.
>
> ## Warning
>
> The session name can't consist of digits only, at least one letter must be present. Otherwise a new session id is generated every time.

If you follow the rules it works as expected:

```
session_name('mxm');
```

To sum up:

- Don't guess, use the browser developer console and other tools
- Read the docs ;-)

---

**Edit:** Just noticed you say this:

> I can not find any hints on the manual page, nor a definition on what is valid characters for a session.

I found that information right in the manual page for [session_name()](https://www.php.net/session_name).

Comment: Yes. I read the manualpage, but obviously not good enough... thanx. I also was expecting a warning stating "invalid characters in session_name, use only [a-z09-]" but I did not get that and could not figure out why. Anyway, good answer.

Comment: @MikaelRoos It'd make sense to be able to find out whether `session_name()` succeeds. And it'd make even more sense that PHP would not proceed normally with an invalid session name. But that's the PHP we all love and hate ;-)

Answer (score -1):

White space in the session_name() will not work.

<strike>session_name('m m');</strike>

session_name('mm');